# Get attached file url from upload WCK Wordpress plugin custom field creator not an image type

Tags: wordpress, plugins

How to get the attached file from WCK plugin in Wordpress eventhough it is not an image? like an audio file.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that I have tried and it works! :)

Below is just an example.

```
<?php
    $wck_custom = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'audiosamps', true);

    foreach($wck_custom as $wck_cstm) {

      $audio_file = $wck_cstm['audio_file'];  

      $src_audio_file = wp_get_attachment_url( $audio_file);

    ?>

  <div class="audio-cont"><audio src="<?php echo $src_audio_file; ?>"></audio></div>

<?php } ?>
```

With the used of `wp_get_attachment_url()` function from Wordpress